# TypeConverters - How to save array of objects to database?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, typeconverter

My JSON looks like this (look at the bonus array of objects):

```
objects:[
{
    name,
    date,
    string,
    string,
        bonus:[
            {
            bonus_name
            bonus_amount
            bonus_imgurl
            },{
            bonus_name
            bonus_amount
            bonus_imgurl
            },{
            bonus_name
            bonus_amount
            bonus_imgurl
            }
        ]
},
    string,
    string,
        bonus:[
            {
            bonus_name
            bonus_amount
            bonus_imgurl
            },{
            bonus_name
            bonus_amount
            bonus_imgurl
            },{
            bonus_name
            bonus_amount
            bonus_imgurl
            }
        ]
}

]
```

I'm already successfully parsing the array of objects to the database where each array gets his own row. I now want to add the bonus to each row with a TypeConverter

```
@Entity(tableName = config.TABLE_EVENTS)
data class RoomEventsModel(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
        var eventName: String?, 
        ....
        @TypeConverters(value = [Converters::class])
        @ColumnInfo(name = "bonus_values") var bonus_value: List<Bonus>
){
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var id: Int? = null
}
```

Converters.class looks like:

```
class Converters : Serializable {
    companion object {
        @TypeConverter
        fun fromBonusList(bonusElements : List<Bonus>): String {
            val gson = Gson()
            val type = object : TypeToken<List<Bonus>>() {
            }.type
            return gson.toJson(bonusElements, type)
        }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toBonusList(bonusElements: String?): ArrayList<HashMap<List<Bonus>, RoomEventsModel>>? {
        if (bonusElements == null) {
            return null
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<Bonus>>() {

        }.type
        return gson.fromJson<ArrayList<HashMap<List<Bonus>,RoomEventsModel>>>(bonusElements, type)
    }
}
```

I added the TypeConverter to my AppDatabase Class

```
 @TypeConverters(value = [Converters::class])
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    ...
}
```

Compiling it says me:

> Class is referenced as a converter but it does not have any converter
>   methods.

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Is your `toOptionValuesList(...)` method meant to be as a supplement to the method `fromBonusList(...)` ? or are they completely unrelated?

Comment: @Christilyn: It should be written the right way now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `toBonusList(...)` method must return `List<Bonus>` in your `Converters` class since you are storing `bonus_value` as a `List<Bonus>` in your data class.

Type converters must have corresponding `toSomeValue()` and `fromSomeValue()` methods where the parameter in `to` method corresponds with the return value of the `from` method, and vice-versa.

Also, try adding `@JvmStatic` to each of your method in your `Converters` class.

```
@TypeConverter
@JvmStatic
    fun toBonusList(bonusElements: String?): List<Bonus> {
        if (bonusElements == null) {
            return null
        }
        val gson = Gson()
        return gson.fromJson(bonusElements, Array<Bonus>::class.java).asList()
    }
```

Comment: Somethings fishy with your Code: found: List<RoomEventsModel> expected: List<Bonus>

Comment: Array<Bonus>::class.java or Array<RoomEventsModel>::class.java?